# How to trigger mouse enter and leave events when the mouse doesn't move

Tags: java, swing

I need to be able to track what component is under the mouse. On the legacy project I'm working on this was done with a MouseListener using mouseEntered() and mouseExited() triggers.

However this does not cover two corner cases

- mouse pointer does not move but the component underneath is removed from display
- mouse pointer does not move but a new component appears underneath the mouse pointer

This means buttons elsewhere in the application associated with what the user currently has the mouse pointer over remain on display even after the components they relate to have disappeared. Normally this would be cleaned up via the mouseExited() trigger.

My best attempt so far, below, is to add ComponentListener and HierarchyListeners to the components I wish to track and use them to trigger a check of the mouse being over them using `button.getMousePosition() != null`. Additionally I then use this to dispatch synthetic MOUSE_ENTER and MOUSE_EXIT events so none of the existing legacy code has to change.

I'm looking for a simpler solution if any exists.

```
public class MouseTracker {

    private static int clock;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("one");
        button1.setName("one");
        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, (e) -> {
            content.removeAll();
            if (clock % 2 == 0) {
                content.add(button1);
            }
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
            clock++;
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        track(button1);
    }

    private static void track(JButton component) {
        component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Mouse enter ");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Mouse exit ");
            }
        });
        component.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                checkMouse(component);
            }

            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
                checkMouse(component);
            }

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                checkMouse(component);

            }

            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                checkMouse(component);
            }

        });
        component.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {
            @Override
            public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
                checkMouse(component);
            }
        });

    }

    private static void checkMouse(JComponent component) {
        Point mousePosition = component.getMousePosition();
        if (component.isShowing() && mousePosition != null) {
            System.out.println("Equivalent mouse enter " + component.getName());
            component.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(component, MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, 0, 0, mousePosition.x,
                    mousePosition.y, 0, false));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Equivalent mouse exit " + component.getName());
            component.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(component, MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try an `AncestorListener`?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland Thanks, no I didn't, but yes I can see how there might be examples where this would be needed, i.e. component moves under the mouse because its parent has moved, but target remained fixed within its parents bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In absense of other suggestions, sticking with current proposed solution.

```
private static void track(JButton component) {
    component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Mouse enter ");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Mouse exit ");
        }
    });
    component.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            checkMouse(component);
        }

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
            checkMouse(component);
        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            checkMouse(component);

        }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
            checkMouse(component);
        }

    });
    component.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {
        @Override
        public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
            checkMouse(component);
        }
    });

}

private static void checkMouse(JComponent component) {
    Point mousePosition = component.getMousePosition();
    if (component.isShowing() && mousePosition != null) {
        System.out.println("Equivalent mouse enter " + component.getName());
        component.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(component, MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, 0, 0, mousePosition.x,
                mousePosition.y, 0, false));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Equivalent mouse exit " + component.getName());
        component.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(component, MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false));
    }
}
```